# Create Collocation with a specific corpus

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am working on a project and I am trying to do some research.  I want to be able to find the collocation of words, using a specific corpus library.  I was hoping there was some SDK I could use to do this type of work.  I looked at this option:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/CollocationFinder.html

and found a class called CollocationFinder but cannot find much documentation or know if there is a way to specify a corpus.

I also found a project called JXtract (http://definingterms.com/projects/Champollion/#smadja93) but it seems to be quite old and the author states that it is sure to have bugs.

Is anyone aware of a good library I could use to develop software in?  Something that will allow for selecting a corpus, as well as maybe selecting different methods for determining a collocation?

Comment: I am not familiar with NLP.  But, considering I haven't received any responses, I am wondering if maybe my question does not make sense?  Or maybe this is something that cannot be accomplished using current software libraries?

Comment: *"I am not familiar with NLP."* Given how much attention you paid to the helpful tag pop-ups for tags like [tag:jnlp], I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not specify that it must be a Java solution, there's [a collocation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/app/collocations_app.html) ([and a concordancer](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/app/concordance_app.html)) [app built using NLTK (Python)](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/app/collocations_app.html). It meets your requirements (a good library [for NLP], allow[s] for selecting a corpus, and you can naturally code any different method for determining a collocation - the TK in NLTK stands for "tool-kit"!)

Comment: yes, this does not have to be done in Java.  Thanks for the recommendation.  I will check this one out.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the CollocationFinder class in Stanford CoreNLP is to merge words together into a single collocation token.  The collocations are found from WordNet, so this class isn't going to help with automatic collocation extraction from a corpus.